# Magento: How to edit the admin panel sales order listing table?

Tags: php, magento

I was wondering if someone could help me as I'm really confused and spent around 2 days so far on this.

I was wondering how I can edit/add columns/manipulate the data in the admin sales order table, eg the list of orders in the admin panel..

What template file controls the formatting of this table?

I would like to do so without editing the core aswell.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: hi, i have tried editing the all the adminhtml > sales files but i cannot find where that table is being processed from. So confused

Comment: You are looking for the sales_flat_order_grid table. You can extend the grid by extending the sales order grid and fill it with your own order attributes (or table columns).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at the EnhancedGrid module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-product-grid.html

You can download the source code [here](http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/TBT_Enhancedgrid/1.3.2.1/TBT_Enhancedgrid-1.3.2.1.tgz). This module also modifies the sales grid (with all the orders). It's possible that you achieve what you are looking for by just installing this module ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you some articles regarding to this question. One of them is mine:

http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/

http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-column-to-customers-grid-alternative-way/

Answer (score 0):

<--Enable Template Hints for Admin-->

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
```

Find Template Path Hints  Around Line 517 change 0 to 1
Find Add Block Names to Hints  Around Line 526 change 0 to 1

This will allow you to view the Template Hints and Block Names for the Admin Panel. You will then be able to figure out which file to edit.

System->Config->Developer->Debug (must be in Default Store)

Best practice is to move this into a Community or Local folder before edit, but for some reason this does not work with system.xml files. So I just have this as a step in my upgrade process.

I know this was an old post but just in case someone comes across this, it may help them out.